# Custom background for Chrome new tab replacement extension

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a new tab replacement extension for Google Chrome and I'd like to allow the user to customize the background, to do so I'm using the [`storage.sync`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#property-sync) API as suggested by [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options) page.

The problem is that the style changes are applied asynchronously, so the default background (white) is briefly used during the page load resulting in unpleasing *flashes*.

Possible (unsatisfying) solutions are:

- do not allow to change the background;
- hard code a black background in the CSS (and move the problem to custom light backgrounds);
- use a CSS transition (still super-ugly).

What could be an alternative approach?

---

Follows a minimal example.

`manifest.json`

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Dummy",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "chrome_url_overrides": {
        "newtab": "newtab.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "storage"
    ]
}
```

`newtab.html`

```
<script src="/newtab.js"></script>
```

`newtab.js`

```
chrome.storage.sync.get({background: 'black'}, ({background}) => {
    document.body.style.background = background;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come up with a reasonable solution. Basically since the [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) API is synchronous we can use it as a cache for [`storage.sync`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#property-sync).

Something like this:

`newtab.js`

```
// use the value from cache
document.body.style.background = localStorage.getItem('background') || 'black';

// update the cache if the value changes from the outside (will be used the next time)
chrome.storage.sync.get({background: 'black'}, ({background}) => {
    localStorage.setItem('background', background);
});

// this represents the user changing the option
function setBackground(background) {
    // save to storage.sync
    chrome.storage.sync.set({background}, () => {
        // TODO handle error
        // update the cache
        localStorage.setItem('background', background);
    });
}
```

This doesn't work 100% of the times but neither do the simple:

```
document.body.style.background = 'black';
```

So it's good enough.¹

---

¹ In the real extension I change the CSS variables directly and I obtain much better results than setting the element style.

Comment: I would also load the script at the start of html when there's no `body` yet, then add a style element under document.documentElement with the color from localStorage inside a CSS rule for `body`. BTW, the default tab background color can be set by a [theme extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/themes), although not all of them do that.